# Can I click on the View under another in ConstraintLayout of AndroidStudio's Layout Editor?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I'm using `ConstrainyLayout`, it's been good to use these days because it supports dragging by mouse in the Layout Editor of Android Studio.

However, I'm wondering, can I use my cursor to click/select a `View` under(covered by) another `View` in the Editor?

For example, I cannot click the 20% `TextView` because it is under another larger `View`.

[image]

Is there any solution? or I just have to use text editor ?

Comment: as long as the view that's 'in the way' is set to not clickable and/or disabled, the touch/click should pass through it and onto the view you want to receive the event. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZAoJU-nUyI

Comment: Sorry, I mean in the editor, I'll update the question.

Comment: You can use the Component Tree at the bottom-left of the layout editor.  I'm not sure if there is any click-shortcut to cycle through stacked views like on IOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Component Tree` feature provided by the layout editor in the `Design` tab. You can select the view you want to access/edit by clicking on it. The view properties will automatically be avaialble to edit in the `Attributes` tab. You can make your changes there.

[image: layout_editor_image]